# Why does getDescription() always return null, even when mail has description?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code:

```
public class tets extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Properties props = System.getProperties();       
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = null; 
        Folder folder = null;
        Message[] messages = null;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com","xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
            folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            messages = folder.getMessages();
            Message Message[] = folder.getMessages();
            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            folder.fetch(messages, fp);                
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Message Count "+folder.getMessageCount());
        //System.out.println("New Message Count "+folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
        //FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
        //fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        //folder.fetch(messages, fp);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);


        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) 
        { 
            //System.out.println("From:"+ messages[i].getFrom());

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            // create a new TextView
            TextView number = new TextView(this);
            number.setOnClickListener(this);
            TextView country = new TextView(this);
            number.setOnClickListener(this);
            // set the text to "text xx"
           try{
                number.setText(messages[i].getDescription().toString());

           }
           catch(MessagingException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace(); 
           }

            //country.setPadding(2, 1, 1, 1);
            // add the TextView
            row.addView(number);
            row.addView(country);
            // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            table.addView(row); 
            }   try {
                            folder.close(true);
                            store.close();
                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("data", ((TextView) v).getText().toString());
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                Details.class);
        newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `folder.getMessages()` gives `null` values